# Boundaries 95% confidence interval and point estimates: can they be equal?

Tags: confidence-interval

Can the point estimate be equal to one of the boundaries of a 95% confidence interval? Or, can the under limit of a 95% confidence interval be equal to the point estimate?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Consider a confidence interval for the parameter of a Bernoulli$(p)$ distribution when $0$ successes are observed in $n$ independent trials.  The answer depends both on the confidence interval procedure and on how you estimate the parameter, but for reasonable CIs (which won't return lower limits smaller than $0$) and the intuitive point estimator $\hat p = 0/n,$ you will have a simple example.  In principle, you could *declare* the point estimate to be the lower limit of any kind of interval.  That would be valid; the issue would concern the statistical properties of that estimator.

Comment: In light of these comments, if you would like to refine or clarify your question, please feel free to edit it here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm reading a report. It says that life time prevalence of an indicator is 3% (95%CI 3 - 5). As all the point estimates use symmetric CI, I find it difficult to understand. We add and distract the same figure from the mean, so how can it be that the upper limit is higher than the point estimate but the lower limit is equal.  I hope that clarifies my question.

Comment: It does.  One is led to suspect a typographical error.  Your question really isn't about statistics, because it comes down to the facts you just gave in the second half of your comment and it doesn't matter whether this is a confidence interval.

Comment: It's possible to get this kind of result if the data are discrete, and a percentile bootstrap method is used for the confidence interval.  For example, with `A = (2,2,2,2,3,4,5)`, using the percentile method for the confidence interval for the median, I get 2, 4.  ...  This wouldn't be a great use of this method.  And it's not clear that something like this would apply in your case.